# How to burn a linux distribution into CD?

Tags: linux, compact-disc

Can someone list the steps?

Answer (score 3):

Burning a linux distribution is the same as burning any image-cd.

You will find recommendations of programs for this task, at this question: https://superuser.com/questions/308/which-iso-burning-software-do-you-recommend

If you choose [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) (which seems to be the most recommended at this link), you will need only to select "Write Image File to Disc", and choose the file you downloaded with the Linux distribution on.

Answer (score 1):

Download all images  ( Linux distributions  CD/DVD 1 to  CD/DVD 3 .. ) from Linux distributions  Site

if you are in windows  use Nero - Burn image to CD /DVD .

In you are in Linux - use @ fellow [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/CD-Writing-HOWTO-3.html)

Answer (score -2):

You could just go to [shipit.ubuntu.com](https://shipit.ubuntu.com/), fill in your details and a get a Ubuntu CD posted to you.

If you want a more detailed reply you'll need to give some details on what OS you currently have.

Comment: Answer linked to Ubuntu only, and recently, they don't ship anymore to everyone. Only to community and contributors (I guess the cost was too big).

Comment: this may or may not result in the desired effect (obtaining an installable linux cd), but it certainly doesn't answer the question of 'how to burn a cd'.

Comment: @Gnoupi - Are you sure about that ? I logged in and saw that I was able to enter the form ( I didn't proceed with submitting it)

Comment: Canonical are limiting the number of CDs you can order, but anyone who hasn't had a Ubuntu CD before can still get one.  http://www.pcpro.co.uk/news/352798/canonical-limits-free-ubuntu-cds